# Conditionally pick same element but with different attribute list

Tags: xml, xsd

Suppose I have the following xml:

```
<root>
    <node attr1="1" />
    <node attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <node attr1="1" attr3="3"/>
</root>
```

atrr1 is required across all nodes except the root, but the other attributes can form a combination. The only combinations allowed are:
1. attr1 by itself
2. attr1, attr2
3. attr1, attr3

attr2 and attr3 cannot show up together in a combination.

I have been trying to use xsd to try and conditionally evaluate the combination of attributes, but it seems almost impossible because I cannot name multiple elements in the xsd file as node. Is there any way around this or to even conditionally check attribute combinations? If not, has anyone seen a work around?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only be able to tell it that attr1 is required, and attr2 and attr3 are optional.  There is no way that I know off defining in a XSD schema (for XML 1.0) that you can't have both attr2 and attr3.
You would have to have something validate it afterwards to check for that combination.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="node">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="attr1" type="xs:int" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="attr2" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
            <xs:attribute name="attr3" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

EDIT:
I came across another thread where someone wanted some complex validation like yours and a link was provided in one of the comments too an article talking about [Co-occurrence constraints](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_constraints) which is what you are after and was implement for XML version 1.1. I also come accross this article  [XML Schema 1.1, Part 2: An introduction to XML Schema 1.1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/) that went into details.  Unfortunately XML 1.1 does not seem to be widely supported.

Comment: oh ok . Yea I think after the basic xml validation, I am just going to very the attribute combinations myself. Thanks!